# Issue with transparent bar on top of iframe, hoping javascript can fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to put a transparent bar on top of an iframe. When I scroll down on the page, I want the transparent bar over the content.

Page should look like this when first loaded: http://cl.ly/image/2V0s2B3P2e3D, then when you scroll down it would look like this: http://cl.ly/image/3x133T3k3a3p

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:60px;background:#000;opacity:0.8;z-index:50;color:#fff;"></div>
<iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org" style="border: 0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%">
```

I'm hoping that some javascript could help me with this, but I'm not very familiar with it so I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Here is an example that does almost what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/VxXA2/ (I don't want the transparent bar over the content right at the top, only once it is scrolled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `iframe` domain is the same from your main page, then it's easy:

1. Set your iframe's `top` position just below the header bar (i.e. `60px`);
2. Listen for the `scroll` event in its contents;
3. Adjust the `top` according to the `scrollTop` property each time the user scrolls the iframe.

HTML (just like yours, just the `top` is changed:

```
<iframe ... style="... top:60px; ...">
```

JavaScript (inside jQuery's `load`):

```
$("iframe").contents().scroll(function(e) {
    var top = 60 - $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( top < 0 )
        top = 0;
    $("iframe").css("top", top);
});
```

Here's a [working demo](https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/iframe_scrolling/outer.html).

---

Original answer (for the case where the domains are different):

If your `iframe` domain is different from your main page's, that will be a bit difficult to do, since you can't (for security reasons) access the DOM elements (or the JavaScript) of the inner page from the outer one - and vice-versa. So, you can't listen for the scroll event of the inner page AFAIK.

Here I'll show an "ugly" workaround: make your `iframe` very big, place it below the bar, and when the user scolls the mouse wheel change the `top` CSS property of the `iframe`. I'm using the [jquery-mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) plugin for that:

```
<iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org" style="border: 0; position:fixed;
 top:60px; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:10000%">

...

$("html, body").mousewheel(function(e,d,dx,dy) {
    var iframe = $("iframe");
    var top = parseInt(iframe.css("top"))+10*dy;
    if ( top > 60 )
        top = 60;
    iframe.css("top", top);
});
```

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VxXA2/1/). The downsides are that there's no visible scrollbar (so the mouse wheel is the only control for scrolling) and there's also no way to adjust the `iframe` height to be as big as the contents (since you can't know its height due to that different origin constraint I mentioned earlier).

Unfortunatly, only in some browsers (such as Chrome) the mouse wheel event will fire when the mouse is over the `iframe`. In others (such as Firefox) it will only work if you scroll the mouse over the transparent bar.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for, but you're right in that it is an "ugly" workaround. For my actual page, the iframe will be on the same domain. Is there a better way?

Comment: @HaroldDunn in this case, you'll probably be able to listen for the `scroll` event of the inner page, and use it to adjust the `top` property the same way I described. I don't know how to do it from the top of my head, but I'll go check it, and come back later if I find a solution.